# Editing a user type inside a map

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I've this table and user types

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS criteria (
    id text,
    enumerate text,
    name text,
    description text,
);

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS module (
    id text,
    enumerate text,
    name text,
    description text,
    criteria map<int, frozen<criteria>>
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS certification (
    id timeuuid,
    owner text,
    description text,
    name text,
    template map<int, frozen<module>>,
    images map<text, text>,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, owner)
);
```

How can I update or add new data in the map with the criteria.

First add data in the template field

```
UPDATE certification set template = template +
{1:{
    id: '***',
    enumerate: '***',
    name: 'aaa',
    description: 'aaa',
    criteria: {}
}}
where owner='***' and id = ***;
```

after that, I want to update the criteria. I was trying this (the certification table already has data and the template field has the map key = 1 ) :

```
UPDATE certification set
template[1].criteria = template[1].criteria +
                {1:{
                    id: 'xxxx',
                    enumerate: 'xxxx',
                    name: 'xxxx',
                    description: 'xxxx'
                }}
where owner='****' and id = ***;
```

or `template[1]['criteria']`

but i get a error.

```
SyntaxException: line 2:27 mismatched input '.' expecting '='
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The field template value is defined as frozen, frozen is immutable**

You can't update frozen item, you have to reinsert with full value.

> A frozen value serializes multiple components into a single value. Non-frozen types allow updates to individual fields. Cassandra treats the value of a frozen type as a blob. The entire value must be overwritten.

Also Cassandra don't support non-frozen field inside collection

Source : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html